# Texboxes empty alert button

Tags: javascript

If I don't input any number in text-boxes I get an alert `NaN` .Instead of that I want an `alert("please input a number")` .

I've try few things but I've got 3 pop'up one with `NaN` and one with my message.

```
function sum() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);
    var sum = (a * b) + (b * c) / (a + b);
    alert("result".value = sum)
}
```

Comment: This is noncense: 'result".value=sum'. Explain, what you want to do here.

Comment: i want to make a popup alert(please insert numbers) insted of NaN..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a variable is a number by using `isNaN`.

```js
function sum() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);

  if (!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b) && !isNaN(c)) {  //Check if all 3 varables are number
    var sum = (a * b) + (b * c) / (a + b);
    alert("result " + sum);
  } else {
    alert("please input a number");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="text" id="num2">
<input type="text" id="num3">

<input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="sum()">
```

Doc: [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Happy to help :)